# replace part of regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace part of the regx match in javascript.

```
Ex: fn_eq("col","va  AND l") AND fn_gt("col","v AND a ")
```

I need to replace the string **AND** sepreated by the expression with some other string, say **||**.

I'm able to match with the above expression with this regx:
`(\w+\((".*?",".*?")\))\s+(AND)\s+(\w+\((".*?",".*?")\))`

How can I replace AND sepreated by the expression(second capturing group), leaving the rest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Difficult, you would use split but then the AND's within would be gone too. Maybe you can use some kind of Regex.Split.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't a simple replace do it for you?

```
var string = 'fn_eq("col","va  AND l") AND fn_gt("col","v AND a ")',
    re = /(\w+\((".*?",".*?")\))\s+(AND)\s+(\w+\((".*?",".*?")\))/;
string = string.replace(re, "$1 || $4");
```

(By the way, `||` usually means the "or" logical operator, not "and".)

Pro-tip: avoid lazy quantifiers if possible. Instead of `.*?`, use `[^"]*`. It's **much** faster.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `"$1 || $4"` here?

Comment: But this expression can go way complex. like., `(fn_eq("col","va  AND l")) AND ((fn_gt("col","v AND a ") OR ..... )).` Is it possible to remove just the capturing group?

Comment: @Pradeep You're capturing 4 groups with that regex. If want to group a sequence without capturing it, use `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`. Also, if you want to *parse* a string, you can't really do it as a whole with a single regex. Try a different approach with a full fledged parser (which may rely on regular expressions, anyway).